# Apache 2.4 is messing up with SSL certificates

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4

I have the following virtual hosts configuration with two SSL certificates
for domains *.example.com and *.dev.example.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/example.key

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.101:8073/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.101:8073/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site.dev.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/dev_example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/dev_example.key

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.102:8073/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.102:8073/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAlias *.dev.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/dev_example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/dev_example.key

    <Proxy balancer://devcluster>
        BalancerMember http://192.168.1.201:8182 
        BalancerMember http://192.168.1.202:8182 
    </Proxy>    
    ProxyPass / balancer://devcluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://devcluster/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/example.key

    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        BalancerMember http://192.168.1.203:8182 
        BalancerMember http://192.168.1.204:8182 
    </Proxy>    
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
</VirtualHost>
```

When accessing web sites I get the following:

1. **site.example.com** has valid certificate for *.example.com from example.crt
2. **site.dev.example.com** has valid certificate for *.dev.example.com from dev_example.crt
3. **anything.dev.example.com** has valid certificate for *.dev.example.com from dev_example.crt
4. *but* **anything.example.com** gets invalid certificate for *.dev.example.com from dev_example.crt spceified in *.dev.example.com virtual host

Looks like virtual host "ServerAlias *.example.com" is picking the certificate specified in virtual host "ServerAlias *.dev.example.com"

Is it Apache glitch or something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick a unique ServerName for each SSL virtual host, even if you expect the ServerAlias to represent what you need. mod_ssl uses the servername as a key for SNI.

Comment: You can still use a serveralias, you just can't Omi ServerName or have dup's